# Possible glitch with GSON? Or bad coding?

Tags: kotlin, gson, sharedpreferences

I came across GSON and I almost fell in love with it. It seemed like a very simple way to instantly save Objects and all the variables contained inside them via shared preferences or internal storage.

The problem is, while my data is successfully persisted when I close and open an app, when I restart the phone the shared preference/internal storage doesn't load the data anymore. They are still there but the data they hold is zero.

For instance, I was able to persist this with no problem

```
fun save() {
getPreferences(0).edit().putString("name", Object.name.toString()).apply()
}

fun load(){

Object.name = JSONArray(getPreferences(0).getString("name", Object.name)
}
```

But any attempt to do the same via GSON conversion failed to produce the same result after phone restart. The data is saved no problem when I just open and close the app though.

```
fun save(){
getPreferences(0).edit().putString("Object", Gson().toJson(Object)).commit()
}

fun load(){
var copiedObject = Gson().fromJson(getPreferences(0).getString("Object", Gson().toJson(Object)), Object.javaClass)

Object.name = copiedObject.name
}
```

I'm not sure if it's due to me incorrectly writing the code for the GSON data saving method. If it was, surely the app wouldn't be able to save data by closing and opening the app alone.

Perhaps if it helps to solve this problem, I have Object stored as a separate .kt file in my app.

Comment: Can you show the error in logcat

Comment: It's not an error. There's literally nothing saved in the shared preference after I restarted the phone.

Comment: If you're using shared preferences as a persistence for data because of some malignant idea (instead of a dedicated data storage solution like Room), then you should at least make sure your string is properly escaped for XML before saving it. Otherwise things can fail.

Comment: Well it failed to save even when I am using internal storage, which I believe is pretty dedicated IMO. Unless I am wrong again?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to store custom objects in SharedPreferences you should consider using Gson with TypeTokens.

For example I will be using custom class Example

```
data class Example(
    val test: String
)
```

First of all you should create your objects once.

```
lateinit var preferences : SharedPreferences
val gson = Gson()
val exampleType = object : TypeToken<Example>() {}.type
```

Then initialize preferences like this (if you are using default SharedPreferences):

```
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
```

Finally you can save/load data using this 2 functions

```
fun load() : Example? {
    return gson.fromJson(preferences.getString("example", null), exampleType) as Example?
}

fun save(example: Example) {
    preferences.edit().putString("example", gson.toJson(example)).apply()

}
```

Comment: Okay, how do I perhaps set my Object to be TypeToken? and what should I put in the <>?

fyi, my Object is a separate kt file and it reads like this:

object Object {var name = JSONArray()} and then I just put values directly into it ie Object.name.put("Billy")

Comment: In <> of TypeToken you should put the type of object that will be stored in SharedPreferences eg. String, Boolean, Any etc. So for example if you define a data class with one field of type JSONArray and name it MyObject your TypeToken will look like this `object : TypeToken<MyObject>() {}.type`

Comment: Thanks. But I'm pretty sure though that a data class ISN'T the same as an object. Probably that's why it still didn't work even when I tried using your solution. The data is saved just fine when I close and open the app but everything is lost when I restart the phone. I guess I'll keep looking.